# Combo Box to Another Combo Box

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have two combo box cmbo1, cmbo2. The cmbo1 has items listed maria,john. The cmbo2 has an empty items

And i want to make an if then statement like this

```
If Me.cmbo1.SelectedItem = "maria" Then
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("female")
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("she")
Else If me.cmbo1.selecteditem = "john" Then
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("male")
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("he")
Else
    Me.cmbo2.Items = ""
End if
```

But instead the cmbo2 added all the items (female,she,male,he) after I selected the second item "john"

Any advice and reconstruction of my code would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must clear the old selection from the list before adding new items using the `Clear` function

```
Me.cmbo2.Items.Clear
If Me.cmbo1.SelectedItem = "maria" Then
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("female")
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("she")
Else If Me.cmbo1.SelectedItem = "john" Then
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("male")
    Me.cmbo2.Items.Add("he")
End If
```